# What happens if we, recursively, change folder permissions after changing files in it?

Tags: linux, debian, files, permissions, chmod

What will these below commands actually do?

```
chmod 777 /yoda/htdocs/cups/logs/*
chmod -R -f 777 /yoda/htdocs/cups/logs/
```

When I check the file permissions in ..../logs folder, they are showing as

```
-rw-r-----
```

But why is this happening when I actually changed the permissions of all the files in the first command itself

Comment: The second `chmod` command should set the permissions as rwxrwxrwx. Is that a typo? Where is the rw-r permission taken from?

Comment: No. it's not a typo. I'm not sure where the rw-r permission is coming from. Is it the second command that is doing something related to it?

Comment: The first command is over-ridden (you don't need it). I have no idea why the second did not do what it should have done. (Have you tried without the `-f`?)

Comment: @TywinLannister Does your user account have the necessary permissions for this 'logs' directory and the files inside it? You could add the output of `ls -l` for the directory and the files so that we can check.

Comment: The files are being created after the permissions are set. Is there any way that I can mention before the files are being created ? so that any file that gets created in the logs folder witll have permissions as **777**

Comment: for new files permission you can use umask in your code through which you are creating files.

Comment: @TywinLannister you are now misleading, that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

**chmod 777 /yoda/htdocs/cups/logs/***
will add 777 permission for all files in logs directory.

**chmod -R 777 /yoda/htdocs/cups/logs/**
will add 777 permission to logs directory and all directories and files inside recursively
for more info check below link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

If you want to assign permission for files which will be created in future.
For that you need to use umask functionality.
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm